# left join with ActiveRecord (yii2)

Tags: activerecord, yii, yii2

I tried to send SQL request with LEFT JOIN but it doesn't display data from `table2` table.

```
public static function top($limit)
{
    return self::findBySql("
        SELECT * FROM table 1 g1 
        LEFT JOIN table2 s1 
        ON (g1.id = s1.g_id AND s1.id = (
            SELECT MAX(id) 
            FROM table2 s2 WHERE s2.g_id = g1.id
        )) 
        LIMIT :limit", 
    [':limit' => $limit]
    )->all();
}
```

Comment: You need to add columns from table2 as well to your select clause.

Comment: @PawełDuda, I tried it. I got same result.

Comment: Try this: SELECT * FROM table 1 g1 
        LEFT JOIN table2 s1 
        ON (g1.id = s1.g_id) WHERE s1.id = (
            SELECT MAX(id) 
            FROM table2 s2 WHERE s2.g_id = g1.id
        )
        LIMIT :limit

Comment: Show DDL SQL your tables.

Comment: Your sql query is incorrect. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you are adding this function to the model and **self** represents the model itself.

Yii will not return results from another table and will be limited to the model only if you are calling the find on a model, instead you need to use a db query as below:

```
    $query = new \yii\db\Query;
    $query->select('*')
            ->from('table 1 g1')
            ->leftJoin('table2 s1', 's1.g_id AND s1.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table2 s2 WHERE s2.g_id = g1.id')  
            ->limit($Limit);
    $command = $query->createCommand();
    $resp = $command->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct SQL query is

```
SELECT * FROM table 1 g1 
        LEFT JOIN table2 s1 
        ON g1.some_field = s1.some_field
```

where  g1.some_field = s1.some_field are the fields that define the join.

Answer (score 0):

I have working code something like...:)
with user and user_friend_list

```
                                 $query = new Query;
                                 $query  ->select(['user.id AS user_id', 'user_friend_list.id'])  
                                        ->from('user')
                                        ->innerJoin('user_friend_list', 'user.email = user_friend_list.email');

                                $command = $query->createCommand();
                                $data = $command->queryAll();
                                foreach($data as $datakey)
                                {
                                    //echo $datakey['id'];
                                    $friendfind = UserFriendList::findOne($datakey['id']);
                                    $friendfind->is_app_using_user_id=$datakey['user_id'];
                                    $friendfind->save();
                                }
```