# leftJoin is returning columns from first table only

Tags: mysql, yii2

The code is in EventUserTypes model

```
$this->find()
        ->select(['event_usertypes.user_type_id' , 'usertypes.name'])
        ->leftJoin('usertypes' , 'event_usertypes.user_type_id = usertypes.id')
        ->where(['event_usertypes.event_id'=>$event_id])
        ->all()
```

There is no  error exept that it is only returning the columns of first table 
and not the joined table. Its been 2 hours and have waisted too much energy on what is going wrong ? Any idea ?

If I select * then it returns all columns of first table

and if do this

```
select(['event_usertypes.user_type_id' , 'usertypes.name'])
```

it only returns event_usertypes.user_type_id not the name from the joined table

Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a direct DB query, to ensure that the `usertypes` table will be available in your query results:

```
$query = new \yii\db\Query;
$query->select(['e.user_type_id', 'u.name'])
      ->from('event_usertypes e')
      ->leftJoin('usertypes u', 'e.user_type_id = u.id')  
      ->where(['e.event_id'=> $event_id]);
$command = $query->createCommand();
$resp = $command->queryAll();
```

Have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971501/left-join-with-activerecord-yii2) which was similar to yours.  Also here is a link to the [Yii documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html), in case this might help.

Comment: Nope nothing has changed

Comment: Why are you using `find()` as opposed to `EventUserTypes::find()` in your code?

Comment: Another question: Can you execute the query you want using raw MySQL successfully?

Comment: $this is an object of `EventUserTypes::find()` so it can be written as `$this->find()`

Comment: You never answered my second question: Is your standard MySQL query working correctly?

Comment: What table does `event_id` belong to?  Can you please add the full table name to this column in your `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I have updated the question see the table name in where clause

Comment: @UzumakiNaruto Have a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971501/left-join-with-activerecord-yii2) which is a similar case to yours.

Comment: It works! thanks. on a side a note is it not possible to do it without `$query = new \yii\db\Query;`

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this

```
$query = new \yii\db\Query;
$query->select(['event_usertypes.user_type_id' , 'usertypes.name'])
        ->from('event_usertypes')
        ->leftJoin('usertypes' , 'event_usertypes.user_type_id = usertypes.id')  
        ->where(['event_id'=> $event_id])->all();
$query->createCommand();
```